# How could I make simple row selections from a database with Boole operations?

Tags: php, split, explode

I have a search engine. I would like to select rows from my table with boolean operations when a user types in a search term. Should I use

```
explode();
```

or maybe

```
split();
```

?

I would like to use the "OR" operator for selecting the rows.

Comment: It depends on how smart the search engine you want to make. I think the question should be not about PHP functions but about the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's [split() function is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php). Don't use it. Instead, try explode(), str_split(), or preg_split().

If you're using a SQL database, such as MySQL or PostgreSQL, test with UNION and UNION ALL instead of OR.  You might be surprised.